# Insert webapi data to indexeddb in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have installed latest cli and latest typescript. Then installed angular2-indexeddb. I followed https://github.com/gilf/angular2-indexeddb guide

I am getting below error while running `ng build --prod`

> cannot find name 'IDBTransactionMode'

Comment: please take a look at this article for using indexeddb in angular2 or angular4. http://ujjwalguptaofficial.blogspot.in/2017/10/angular4-crud-operation-in-indexeddb.html

Comment: Thanks ujjwal.I think it will be more helpful for me

Comment: hi,I followed this document and tried to create database.But I am getting error like "Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: JsStore is not defined"

Comment: hi,this error is fixed by including jsstore path in package.json

Comment: It is working fine.Thank you

Comment: Add a issue in stackoverflow. Please dont chat here like this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should be `IDBTransaction.mode`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBTransaction/mode

Comment: thanks kemsky,I am new to angular.I am getting this error in typescript.This document is for js.Please give me idea for working with typescript

Answer (score 0):

Some time the object not be available in those case just declare a variable in same dame. once it compile everything is JavaScript so it will work

In you case just try by declaring `var IDBTransactionMode` in first line.